# @Version annotation not increment in one to many relationship

Tags: spring, version-control, entity, one-to-many

I have problem with @Version annotation. I have ParkingEntity with field and annotation @Version.

```
public class ParkingEntity {
@Id
@Column(name = "parking_id")
private String idParking;
private String name;
private String address;
private int numberOfParkingSlots;
private int numberOfChargers;
private boolean isLPGAllowed;
private Double widthOfSlot;
@OneToMany(mappedBy= "parking")
private Set<CarEntity> cars = new HashSet<>();
@Version
private Integer version;
```

When I am doing update for that entity, column version increments, it works correctly, but when I want to put CarEntity to set of cars it fail. Column annotation does not change.
I am adding and removing car in methods in ParkingEntity:

```
public void addCar(CarEntity carEntity) {
    cars.add(carEntity);
    carEntity.setParking(this);
}

public void removeCar(CarEntity carEntity) {
    cars.remove(carEntity);
    carEntity.setParking(null);
}
```

I can not get why it does not works. I tried with parkingRepository.saveAndFlush but the problem still exists.

Comment: As I know, @Version annotation should annotate `Long` or `long` types

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i changed it but it is still the same result, after adding car to set of cars version not increment :/

Comment: Ok, I now understand. Do not use entities as Spring beans, the are JPA entities and all that you've done in the ParkingEntity JPA does automatically, if you use Hibernate, for example, it depends on JPA implementation you use. Entities just need to store data. So the best answer, I guess, is to read some article on how to use your JPA implementation, I'm not even sure that you use `@Entity` annotation, because it's missed in the snippet :-(. You can read official documentation of your JPA implementation, for example, [this](https://hibernate.org/search/). Best Regards!

Comment: I am using @Entity :) When i update any field of ParkingEntity its ok, version increment. But even if i want to set  any new set<CarEntity> version does not change...